# Cannot replace values in factor level variable

Tags: r, string, replace, na

I found the text of certain cell entries in my dataframe to be garbled and would like to replace them with string, but R returns the following message

```css
#load data from dropbox
library(foreign)
data <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/anm8xrovxc5xtr5/comtrade2009.csv?dl=1")
unique(data$ptTitle)[75]
[1] <NA>
#this is not an NA because the text on the CSV file appears to be some garbled string due to encoding, 
#it shows "C<U+00F4>te d'Ivoire"

data$ptTitle[data$ptTitle == <NA>] <- "Cote d'Ivoire"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ct2009$ptTitle == "<NA>", value = c(238L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

it does not allow me to replace those garbled character values with character string, does anyone know how to overwrite those garbled characters with my preferred character string?

**Update**

So I guess a better way to work around this is to add `stringsAsFactors=F` when loading csv file using `read.csv`, so it's much easier to replace cell values with `NA` (instead of `<NA>`).
Sorry for all the hassles this thread might have caused.

Comment: To capture NA in R, `is.na(data$ptTitle)`

Comment: `<NA>` means it's a factor, and the thread marked by user zx8754 did not actually answer my question.

Comment: I guess a better alternative to work around this is to add `stringsAsFactors=F` when loading the data using `read.csv`, so it's easier to replace those `NA` (instead of `<NA>`).

Comment: There is one NA row in data, row 94. Linked post solution works. Try: `data$ptTitle <- addNA(data$ptTitle)`, this will add NA as a new factor level, then we can change to something else, again from the linked post: `levels(data$ptTitle) <- c(head(levels(data$ptTitle), -1), "Cote d'Ivoire")`

Comment: The strange thing is that after all these replacement tricks, that cell still maintains its garbled format `C<U+00F4>te d'Ivoire`.

Comment: Some updates here, after I applied your code `data$ptTitle <- addNA(data$ptTitle)` and used `data$ptTitle[data$ptTitle == "C<U+00F4>te d'Ivoire"] <- "Cote d'Ivoire"` again, it does work, but this line of code `levels(data$ptTitle) <- c(head(levels(data$ptTitle), -1), "Cote d'Ivoire")` doesn't do the trick, at least not here. Could you paste your proposed solution here as a comment? So I can mark this as solution, which might help others.